# StateFieldPathExpression error on DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm finding hard to discover why this simple Doctrine's DQL is generating the "Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression" error:

```
SELECT a.state
  FROM MyBundle:Alocation a JOIN a.state JOIN a.client
 WHERE a.client = :client
```

I got 3 entities: State(id, name), Client(id, name) and Alocation(id, state, client). What I what is get the states present in alocation for a specific client. I got dozens of simple DQLS like this in the my system. What's the problem of this DQL ?

I've seen my questions here on SO and other places but most uses createQueryBuilder() and I'm using DQL. The questions I found who use DQL doesn't seem to apply to my case.

**Edit:**

Anyway I try to use createQueryBuilder() like this:

```
$this->doctrine->getManager()
->createQueryBuilder()
->add('select', 'a.state')
->add('from', 'MyBundle:Alocation a')
->innerJoin('a.state', 'st')
->innerJoin('a.client', 'c', 'WITH', 'a.client = :client')
->setParameter("client", $client)
->getQuery()
```

same error.

**Edit2:**

I tried to use partial to solve it, like this:

```
SELECT PARTIAL a.{state}
  FROM MyBundle:Alocation a JOIN a.state JOIN a.client
 WHERE a.client = :client
```

but it didn't work. Got the error: "Expected end of string, got 'a' ". I also tried to use WITH instead of WHERE.Same thing.

**Edit3:** What I'm trying to do is to get the State entity ONLY. I can solve it loading all the Alocation entity. But I don't want to load more data than I need.

Comment: you can fetch fields that you need: `select s.id, s.name, s.test`

Comment: if I try to fetch only the a.state field it goes back to the StateFieldPathExpression error

Answer (score 1):

if your state field have Few field number, you can use this query:

```
SELECT s.name, s.id, s.value
  FROM MyBundle:Alocation a JOIN a.state s JOIN a.client c
 WHERE c.id = :client
```

Comment: But then I would get the separated fields, not the entity. And why would a low id matter ?